# Running script against all partner tenants

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am an admin for our company's Microsoft Partner Center 365 for our customers. We have a need to run the following script on all of our tenants. Due to the tenants adding and removing users, we have been tasked with running this once a month on all users to make sure we get all the new users.

```
#This script will enable non-owner mailbox access auditing on every mailbox in your tenancy
#First, let's get us a cred!
$userCredential = Get-Credential

#This gets us connected to an Exchange remote powershell service
$ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $userCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $ExoSession

#Enable global audit logging
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true -AuditLogAgeLimit 180 -AuditAdmin Update, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create, UpdateFolderPermission -AuditDelegate Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, Create, UpdateFolderPermissions, MoveToDeletedItems, SendOnBehalf -AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermission, MailboxLogin, Create, SoftDelete, HardDelete, Update, MoveToDeletedItems 

#Double-Check It!
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select Name, AuditEnabled, AuditLogAgeLimit | Out-Gridview
```

I Manually ran this script by getting the admin username and password for all of our customers, very time consuming.

Is there a way to run this script for all of our tenants without having to manually log in as each one from the partner center powershell, or another solution?

Comment: how do you get the credentials?

Comment: For reference:https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1772604-run-powershell-script-against-multiple-tenants

Comment: @arcset I get them from our secret server and paste them into the $cred = get-credential.

Comment: Is it thycotic?

Comment: @arcset Indeed it is

Comment: @ArcSet Is there a integration between powershell and thycotic?

Comment: Yes yes there is. I wrote a script for it but it depends on alot of stuff. Ill post what i can. Acually if you make a new post about thycotic intergration i could post it but this question is alot more then just getting databack from thycotic

Comment: @ArcSet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160987/thycotic-secret-server-pass-creds-to-powershell

Answer (score 0):

So from what i can tell based off of comments you are looking for away to get passwords from Thycotic Server and pass them into your script.

I wrote a function for this awhile ago. It has mandatory fields of `-WebService`, `-Credential`, and `-SearchTerm`

```
function Get-Secret{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [string] $WebService,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [pscredential] $Credential,
        [string] $Organization = $Null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $SearchTerm = $Null,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Only',Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch] $CountOnly,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Only',Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch] $SummeryOnly,
        [switch] $Raw
    )

    $Service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $WebService -UseDefaultCredential
    $LoginResult = $Service.Authenticate($($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Username), $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password), $Organization, $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain))
    if($LoginResult.errors){
        throw $LoginResult.errors
        return
    }

    $Secret_IDs = $Service.SearchSecrets($LoginResult.token, $searchTerm, $true, $true)
    if($Secret_IDs.errors){
        throw $Secret_IDs.errors
        return
    }

    if($CountOnly){
        return $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries.count
    }
    if($SummeryOnly){
        return $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries
    }

    $Response = @()
    foreach($Secret_ID in $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries){
        $Secret = $Service.GetSecret($LoginResult.token, $Secret_ID.SecretID, $false, $null).secret
        $Response += $Secret
    }

    if($Raw){
        return $Response
    }else{
        return $Response | Foreach-object{
            Write-Output "$($_.Name)"
            Foreach($item in $_.Items){
                Write-Output "$($item.FieldDisplayName) : $($item.Value)"
            }
            Write-Output "`r`n"
        }
    }
}
```

Has the most basic usage as

```
Get-Secret -WebService "PlaceWebServiceAddressHere" -Credential $(get-Credential)  -SearchTerm "SearchString"
```

The web service is a Soap service and will depend on how you login to Thycotic.
Something along the lines of `https://{YourBaseThycoticAddress}/webservices/sswebservice.asmx`

using the -raw parameter you can get the direct object returned from Thycotic

```
Get-Secret -WebService "PlaceWebServiceAddressHere" -Credential $(get-Credential)  -SearchTerm "SearchString" -raw
```

This object you can narrow down to whatever field you are looking you (in this case username)

```
Get-Secret -WebService "PlaceWebServiceAddressHere" -Credential $ThycoticCredentials  -SearchTerm $_ -Raw | select -ExpandProperty Items | ?{$_.fieldname -like 'username'}
```

even get the value

```
Get-Secret -WebService "PlaceWebServiceAddressHere" -Credential $ThycoticCredentials  -SearchTerm $_ -Raw | select -ExpandProperty Items | ?{$_.fieldname -like 'username'} | Select -expandProperty Value
```

So your final script should look something like

```
function Get-Secret{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [string] $WebService,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [pscredential] $Credential,
        [string] $Organization = $Null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $SearchTerm = $Null,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Only',Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch] $CountOnly,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Only',Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch] $SummeryOnly,
        [switch] $Raw
    )

    $Service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $WebService -UseDefaultCredential
    $LoginResult = $Service.Authenticate($($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Username), $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password), $Organization, $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain))
    if($LoginResult.errors){
        throw $LoginResult.errors
        return
    }

    $Secret_IDs = $Service.SearchSecrets($LoginResult.token, $searchTerm, $true, $true)
    if($Secret_IDs.errors){
        throw $Secret_IDs.errors
        return
    }

    if($CountOnly){
        return $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries.count
    }
    if($SummeryOnly){
        return $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries
    }

    $Response = @()
    foreach($Secret_ID in $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries){
        $Secret = $Service.GetSecret($LoginResult.token, $Secret_ID.SecretID, $false, $null).secret
        $Response += $Secret
    }

    if($Raw){
        return $Response
    }else{
        return $Response | Foreach-object{
            Write-Output "$($_.Name)"
            Foreach($item in $_.Items){
                Write-Output "$($item.FieldDisplayName) : $($item.Value)"
            }
            Write-Output "`r`n"
        }
    }
}


$SearchTerms = @("CompanyOne","CompanyTwo")
$ThycoticCredentials = Get-Credentials

$SearchTerms | %{
    Get-Secret -WebService "PlaceWebServiceAddressHere" -Credential $ThycoticCredentials  -SearchTerm $_ -Raw | select -ExpandProperty Items
    $Username = $Obj | ?{$_.fieldname -like 'username'} | select -ExpandProperty value
    $Password = $Obj | ?{$_.fieldname -like 'password'} | select -ExpandProperty value
    $UserCredential = New-Object pscredential($Username,$Password)

    $ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $userCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $ExoSession

    #Enable global audit logging
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true -AuditLogAgeLimit 180 -AuditAdmin Update, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create, UpdateFolderPermission -AuditDelegate Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, Create, UpdateFolderPermissions, MoveToDeletedItems, SendOnBehalf -AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermission, MailboxLogin, Create, SoftDelete, HardDelete, Update, MoveToDeletedItems 

    #Double-Check It!
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select Name, AuditEnabled, AuditLogAgeLimit | Out-Gridview
}
```

this is assuming you enter in correct Search Terms that narrow it down to one user. and the fields in Thycotic are Username and Password