# Thycotic Secret Server Pass Creds to Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get credentials straight out of Thycotic Secret Server through powershell instead of copying and pasting each and every username/password. Has anyone came across this before?

Comment: A better area to ask this question would be on super user - https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function just for this type of thing.

Mandatory fields are

`-Webservice` which needs to be point to `sswebservice.asmx` usually located as `https://{Base Address}/webservices/sswebservice.asmx`

`-Credential` which is your Thycotic login.

`-searchTerm` which is the string you are searching for.

```
function Get-Secret{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [string] $WebService,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [pscredential] $Credential,
        [string] $Organization = $Null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $SearchTerm = $Null,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Only',Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch] $CountOnly,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Only',Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch] $SummeryOnly,
        [switch] $Raw
    )

    $Service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $WebService -UseDefaultCredential
    $LoginResult = $Service.Authenticate($($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Username), $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password), $Organization, $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain))
    if($LoginResult.errors){
        throw $LoginResult.errors
        return
    }

    $Secret_IDs = $Service.SearchSecrets($LoginResult.token, $searchTerm, $true, $true)
    if($Secret_IDs.errors){
        throw $Secret_IDs.errors
        return
    }

    if($CountOnly){
        return $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries.count
    }
    if($SummeryOnly){
        return $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries
    }

    $Response = @()
    foreach($Secret_ID in $Secret_IDs.SecretSummaries){
        $Secret = $Service.GetSecret($LoginResult.token, $Secret_ID.SecretID, $false, $null).secret
        $Response += $Secret
    }

    if($Raw){
        return $Response
    }else{
        return $Response | Foreach-object{
            Write-Output "$($_.Name)"
            Foreach($item in $_.Items){
                Write-Output "$($item.FieldDisplayName) : $($item.Value)"
            }
            Write-Output "`r`n"
        }
    }
}
```

Basic Usage

```
Get-Secret -WebService "https://Stuff/sswebservice.asmx" -Credential $ThycoticCredentials  -SearchTerm "HELLO"
```

Other usages is the parameter `-raw`. This will return an object based on the return from Thycotic.

You can narrow down to the field items

```
Get-Secret -WebService "https://Stuff/sswebservice.asmx" -Credential $ThycoticCredentials  -SearchTerm "HELLO" -raw | select -ExpandProperty Items
```

And even narrow down to values (this one getting field Username)

```
Get-Secret -WebService "https://Stuff/sswebservice.asmx" -Credential $ThycoticCredentials  -SearchTerm "HELLO" -raw | select -ExpandProperty Items | ?{$_.fieldname -like 'username'} | select -ExpandProperty value
```